# failed to intall on the right disk

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, usb, lts

so today i got my server and i tried to install ubuntu server 14.04 LTS from my Universal Serial Bus stick and i have 8 disk on the server with 148 gb on each, when i get to the point where i am going to choose a disk then i do so. after the installation it installed it on the Universal Serial Bus and not on the disk. I have tried to do the thing i can do and i need help. when i try to boot from disks i get this message (trying to boost from (C:) drive) and when i boot from the Universal Serial Bus i get into the OS (from the Universal Serial Bus)

Comment: Universal Serial Bus = USB

Answer (score 0):

The only way forward is to reinstall it on the proper disk since you installed it to the wrong disk.

Or try cloning the USB disk using CloneZilla and restoring the clone onto the required disk.